# Capture and broadcast the group video call

Tags: azure, azure-communication-services

We've made a group call service by using [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/samples/calling-hero-sample?pivots=platform-web) with ACS (Azure Communication Services), but now we want that call to be broadcasted (via youtube, twitch, etc.).

Unfortunately, the ACS doesn't provide such functionality, so we've tried to use the [Video Call Recording](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-recording) to capture the stream if possible and broadcast it, but weren't able, as the recording appears after the call only.

So, is there a way to capture and broadcast the group call event of ACS?
Any method (even hacky ones) is welcome!

P.S. For now I'm checking a way of capturing all the streams right from the browser, to see if I can craft another stream for broadcast, but not sure if that's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question.

For right now, there are no live event capabilities supported within ACS. These capabilities are on the road map but will not be released during calendar year 2021.

In the meantime, you can look into something like Azure Media Services. They support the ingestion of an input URL. For more information on this, I found this 3rd party blog post helpful, which can be found [here](https://dsayed.medium.com/live-streaming-with-microsoft-azure-eb6408d31ed).

Please let us know if there are further questions or concerns regarding this topic.